# How pass form input to subroutine from perl script

Tags: forms, perl

I have a little mini-perl webserver which calls http_handler.pl which has some code to take form input.

For this part in http_handler:

`print $fh '<FORM action="/hello_post.pl" method="POST">First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br> Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"></FORM>';`

.... how can I have the user input pass to the hello_post.pl subroutine ?  I'd have to require hello_post.pl (in either http_handler.pl or pl-websrv.pl ?), but then how would I change that print statement to have the form input just passed to the hello_post.pl subroutine and then displayed on the page?

What I actually want to end up doing is different then just inputting/displaying back names, but I am just cobbling together others' code to see if I can get the concept of this down... Any help would be great! Thanks!

Here are the 3 files (pl-websrv.pl, http_handler.pl, and hello_post.pl)

http://pastebin.com/iPN3WwqC

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing a hello_post.pl file something like the below that just echos all of the parameters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new();

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";

print "hello_post.pl output:\n";

my $params = $cgi->Vars();
foreach my $arg ( sort keys %$params ) {
   print "$arg  ==>  ", $cgi->param($arg), "\n";
}
```